# Inkscape objects lose transparency when saved as a PDF

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

I've seen a number of issues dealing with saving inkscape drawings as anything other than a svg but haven't seen a discussion specifically about transparent objects in PDFs. What's happening is that when I export a png any transparent object looks fine but if I save it as a PDF or eps the transparency is lost. 
 I've created an example which you can see at this link ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwbNI.jpg )

I've looked at a lot of other posts and feel like the explanation to this is layered within the responses but I'm a beginner and can't read between the lines to understand it. I wanted to just ask why this is happening and what can be done about it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Alpha Channel to set the transparency instead of Opacity option.

[image: Click here to find alpha channel]

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is an issue with the pdf printing program that you are using. Perhaps it's a configuration issue, perhaps it's just not advanced enough to handle it.

Try out several other programs that can print to pdf and see if you can find one that works for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your response @rlb.usa. Could you clarify one part of the comment for me? What do you mean by the "pdf printing program"? For the example I've linked in my post, I am saving the pdf within inkscape GUI (file -> save as->pdf) and then opening the pdf in adobe acrobat. Are you saying that inkscape is the pdf printing program in this case? If that is what you are saying, could you please expand upon how I can print my inkscape made vector maps though a different program?

Comment: @AndrewTLombardo There are different third-party programs that you can install on your computer that will let you print any file as a PDF. For example, NitroPrinter. You could File -> Print -> (choose driver as "printer")  -> (save location to)

Comment: @AndrewTLombardo Please understand that I do not know which one will work best for you, you will have to experiment on your own with different programs and settings, or even the settings in your own Inkscape program.